# Do the sum of a positive semi-definite matrix and a matrix which eigenvalues are positive or egal to zero have positive or egal to zero eigenvalues?

Tags: spectral-theory, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Let's **M** be a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix and **N** a non symmetric matrix which all eigenvalues are positive or egal to zero.

The question is : Do the eigenvalues of the matrix **M+N** are all positive or egal to zero?

I have any clue for a proof, neither a counter example.

I write a small code that construct random matrices **M** and **N** with the good properties and check if the eigenvalues of **M+N** are positive or egal to zero. I let the code run for 5h and it found any counter example.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
M = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
2 & -1 \\ 
-1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
and
$$
N = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & -12 \\ 
0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
so that
$$
M+N = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
3 & -13 \\ 
-1 & 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's just elaborate on the example of @Will Jagy:  take a positive definite matrix and add to it an upper triangular matrix with positive diagonal:

$$\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\b&d\end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix}1& t \\0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Its determinant is a linear function in $t$ with $-b$ the coefficient of $t$, so it can take any possible value, including negative ones.